# MVP Candidate not on 1st Team

Tags: nba, awards

Has there ever been an MVP candidate that was not on the All NBA 1st team but listed on the 2nd/3rd team? I just want to know how realistically possible would it be to finish 2nd in MVP voting for the season and not be in the 1st team.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In summary, it is realistically possible to finish high in MVP voting and not be on the 1st All-NBA team. The information below shows when this has happened among the top three candidates for MVP in a given season.

<sub>NOTE: Unless otherwise noted, the following players made 2nd All-NBA team.</sub> †<sub>Did not make an All-NBA team</sub>

---

**Out of MVP winners** in a given season, the following did not make 1st All-NBA team that season:

1972-1973 - Dave Cowens<sub>([1](http://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_1973.html))</sub>.

1957-1958, 1960-1961, 1961-1962 - Bill Russell<sub>([2](http://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_1958.html))([3](http://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_1961.html))([4](http://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_1962.html))</sub>.

---

> I just want to know how realistically possible would it be to finish 2nd in MVP voting for the season and not be in the 1st team.

**Out of MVP candidates who finished second in voting for MVP** in a given season, the following did not make 1st All-NBA team that season:  <sub>NOTE: The 3rd All-NBA team was not introduced until the 1988-1989 season<sub>([5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All-NBA_Team#1988.E2.80.9389_to_present))</sub></sub>.

1994-1995 - Shaquille O' Neal<sub>([6](http://www.basketball-reference.com/awards/awards_1995.html#mvp))</sub>.

1993-1994 - David Robinson<sub>([7](http://www.basketball-reference.com/awards/awards_1994.html#mvp))</sub>.

1976-1977 - Bill Walton<sub>([8](http://www.basketball-reference.com/awards/awards_1977.html#mvp))</sub>.

1975-1976 - Bob McAdoo†<sub>([9](http://www.basketball-reference.com/awards/awards_1976.html#mvp))</sub>.

1974-1975 - Dave Cowens<sub>([10](http://www.basketball-reference.com/awards/awards_1975.html#mvp))</sub>.

1973-1974 - Bob McAdoo<sub>([11](http://www.basketball-reference.com/awards/awards_1974.html#mvp))</sub>.

1968-1969 - Willis Reed<sub>([12](http://www.basketball-reference.com/awards/awards_1969.html#mvp))</sub>.

1967-1968 - Lenny Wilkins†<sub>([13](http://www.basketball-reference.com/awards/awards_1968.html#mvp))</sub>.

1966-1967 - Nate Thurmond†<sub>([14](http://www.basketball-reference.com/awards/awards_1967.html#mvp))</sub>.

1959-1960 - Bill Russell<sub>([15](http://www.basketball-reference.com/awards/awards_1960.html#mvp))</sub>.

---

**Out of MVP candidates who finished third in voting for MVP**, the following did not make 1st All-NBA team that season:

2013-2014 - Blake Griffin<sub>([16](http://www.basketball-reference.com/awards/awards_2014.html#mvp))</sub>.

2012-2013 - Carmelo Anthony<sub>([17](http://www.basketball-reference.com/awards/awards_2013.html#mvp))</sub>.

2003-2004 - Jermaine O' Neal<sub>([18](http://www.basketball-reference.com/awards/awards_2004.html#mvp))</sub>.

1999-2000 - Alonzo Mourning<sub>([19](http://www.basketball-reference.com/awards/awards_2000.html#mvp))</sub>.

1975-1976 - Dave Cowens<sub>([9](http://www.basketball-reference.com/awards/awards_1976.html#mvp))</sub>.

1973-1974 - Bob Lanier†<sub>([11](http://www.basketball-reference.com/awards/awards_1974.html#mvp))</sub>.

1971-1972 - Wilt Chamberlain<sub>([20](http://www.basketball-reference.com/awards/awards_1972.html#mvp))</sub>.

1969-1970 - Kareem Abdul Jabbar<sub>([21](http://www.basketball-reference.com/awards/awards_1970.html#mvp))</sub>.

1963-1964, 1966-1967 - Bill Russell<sub>([22](http://www.basketball-reference.com/awards/awards_1964.html#mvp))([14](http://www.basketball-reference.com/awards/awards_1967.html#mvp))</sub>.

---

[Here](http://www.basketball-reference.com/awards/all_league.html) is a reference for All-NBA (and All-ABA) teams and [here](http://www.basketball-reference.com/awards/mvp.html) is a reference for all NBA MVPs, and from there, you can search each year's MVP voting by clicking on the "(V)."